# Переход в react native как в приложении телеграмм - кошелек

Tags: ios, react-native

Столкнулся с тем. что необходимо сделать переход как указано в названии в приложении телеграмм на ios, возможна ли такая реализация на react native?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пересмотрел документацию и различные библиотеки. но ответа так и не нашел

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.